# Adding Static Button to MenuItem when binded to ItemSouce

Tags: c#, wpf

i have an observable collection as ItemSource for my menuitems.
i want a simple button (see commented part) at end of menu item list that can add new item to this collection.
it seem simple But it throw a System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException in my code telling the collection is already in use.
what is the correct way to achieve this?

```
 <Menu Background="Transparent">
            
                    <MenuItem Header="WorkSpace" Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding  NosWorkSpaces}">
                 
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate >

                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Content="{Binding Original.Title}"></Label>
                                <Button Content="Select"   Tag="WorkSpace_Load"  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=mah:MetroWindow}, Path=DataContext.SelectWorkspaceCommand}"        CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
                                <Button Content="Load"   Tag="WorkSpace_Load"  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=mah:MetroWindow}, Path=DataContext.LoadBinaryWorkspace}"        CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
                                <Button Content="Save"   Tag="WorkSpace_Save"  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=mah:MetroWindow}, Path=DataContext.SaveWorkspaceCommand}"        CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>  
                     
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <!--      <Button Content="New " />  this wont work -->

                </MenuItem>

            </Menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well i found a solution mixing some answer, even i find it not so easy for a simple menu.

```
   <Menu Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Menu.Resources>
                    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding NosWorkSpaces}" x:Key="YourMenuItems"/>
                </Menu.Resources>
                <MenuItem Header="WorkSpaces" >
               
                        <MenuItem.ItemsSource>
                            <CompositeCollection>
                                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource YourMenuItems}}" />
                           
                                    <Separator></Separator>
                                <MenuItem Header="Add Worspace"  />
                               
                    
                            </CompositeCollection>
                        </MenuItem.ItemsSource>
                        <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>

                            <DataTemplate >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Original.Title}"></Label>
                                    <Button Content="Select"   Tag="WorkSpace_Load"  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=mah:MetroWindow}, Path=DataContext.SelectWorkspaceCommand}"        CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
                                    <Button Content="Load"   Tag="WorkSpace_Load"  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=mah:MetroWindow}, Path=DataContext.LoadBinaryWorkspace}"        CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
                                    <Button Content="Save"   Tag="WorkSpace_Save"  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=mah:MetroWindow}, Path=DataContext.SaveWorkspaceCommand}"        CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
     
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
```

giving a mixed menu with itemSource and datatemplate.

[image]